# Accessing Azure SQL Service from IP Range

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, firewall

My application needs to establish a connection to my Azure SQL Database. But I cannot configure each IP Address manually in the firewall, because the application (Desktop App) will run in customers office from a variety of locations.

I also don't want to add the range (0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255) for security reasons.

But I know, the connection requests will only come from locations in germany. Is it possible to restrict the IP Range to german IP addresses?

If not, whats the possibility to achive maximum security and allow easy access to my customers?

Comment: Rely on IP address geolocation is insecure, as people may use VPN to access your site.

Comment: So I guess the only possibility would be adding the entire IP Range in the Firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow access to anyone is indeed a bad practice, even if you would be able to restrict access to geolocation, it is still insecure.

Although, there is no alternative configuration since all of your clients have different ip addresses that doesn't belong to a specific (company) range.

In this case the only option is to have an intermediary service (WCF service for example) that accepts user's requests, authenticates them, and provides the data. This service in turn would communicate with SQL Azure.

Good luck!